# WPF Combobox highlight broken in windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

This works with .net 4.0/4.5 on window 7

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Red</SolidColorBrush>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem >ITem 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >ITem 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >ITem 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >ITem 1</ComboBoxItem>

            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
```

But on windows 8 I still get the OS highlight.

Any body know the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 8 theme doesn't use system colors for the foreground/background colors, so overriding them doesn't work any more. You have to specify a custom control template to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Window8 with me but can you try this to see if this works -

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">#FFFF0000
</SolidColorBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF this resources are dynamics and depends of the OS. Maybe this Brush has changes in Windows 8. If this is the case, then you should to implement the brush. Hope this answer be helpful to you...